# Multi language Supports in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, multilingual

I created one apps and successfully submitted into AppStore. Now my client wants to support multi language like Portuguese, French, Chinese, etc., into my apps. How do i create multi language supports in my application?, Is there any sample application or tutorials available?. Is it possible to create multi language in iPhone?. (I have seen in my device, settings -> general -> International -> Language -> Choose Language Options). But it does affect all the application in my device. But its not solution for that. So how do i create?

Please Guide me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to internationalize your app using multiple XIBs and/or `strings` files.  I strongly recommend reading [Apple's documentation on the process](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can support multiple languages. Most of the information is here http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/